# curl causing gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file

Tags: curl

The following two commands are failing to uncompress the gz files:

```
curl -J -O --compressed http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/wgs/?download=JHQJ01.2.bbs.gz | gunzip -
curl -J -H -O 'Accept-encoding: gzip' http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/wgs/?download=JHQJ01.2.bbs.gz | gunzip -
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `-O` option. That options means to write it to a file based on the download. By default, curl send it to standard out, which is what you want in order to pipe it to the next command.